# LIMIT only the join in query?

Tags: php, mysql, join

Okay, so i want to display some products on a page. 
But I also need their images displayed. To do that I need to join my "produkter" table with my "billeder" table. - But when I run the query with the join in it to get the images it displays the product as many times as there is an image for it.

This is the join I made.

```
$query = "
SELECT p.p_id
     , p.vare_nr
     , p.produkt_navn
     , p.beskrivelse
     , p.forhandler_pris
     , p.kunde_pris
     , p.kategori
     , p.teknisk_info
     , p.hmi_link
     , p.datablad
     , p.public
     , b.b_id
     , b.navn
  FROM produkter p
  JOIN billeder b
    ON p.p_id = b.p_id
 WHERE p.kategori = 'leje'
";
```

But as you can see here
[image: join]

The product is now displayed 5 times before it goes on to the next product.
Is there any way to limit only the JOIN part to only grab the first image it finds in the DB of a product?

Here is my php code:

```
$query = "SELECT produkter.p_id, produkter.vare_nr, produkter.produkt_navn, produkter.beskrivelse, produkter.forhandler_pris, produkter.kunde_pris, produkter.kategori, produkter.teknisk_info,         produkter.hmi_link, produkter.datablad, produkter.public, billeder.b_id, billeder.p_id, billeder.navn
        FROM produkter
        INNER JOIN billeder
        ON produkter.p_id=billeder.p_id
        WHERE produkter.kategori='leje'";
        if($result = $db->query($query)) {
            $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
            if($num_rows == 0) {
                echo "Der er endnu ikke nogle produkter.";
            } else {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo "


                    <div class='cat_travel col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>
                         <div class='portfolio_item'> <a href='lejer.php?page=".$row['p_id']."' data-path-hover='M 180,190 0,158 0,0 180,0 z'>

                             <figure style='background-image:url(../images/p-img/".$row['navn'].")'>


                                   <svg viewBox='0 0 180 320' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
                                        <path d='M 180,0 0,0 0,0 180,0 z'/>
                                   </svg>
                                   <figcaption>
                                        <p>Description of the project dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, mauesris condime ntum nibh, ut fermentum....</p>
                                        <div class='view_button'>View</div>
                                   </figcaption>
                              </figure>
                              </a>
                              <div class='portfolio_description'>
                                   <h3><a href='lejer.php?page=".$row['p_id']."'>".$row['produkt_navn']."</a></h3>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>


                    ";
                }
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
```

Comment: Please post the output from your query in a SQL client so we can see how the rows are structured, and also post the relevant PHP code which displays the data. This sounds like a group display issue more than a querying issue, though it may be possible to change the SQL to use GROUP_CONCAT(). Can't say without seeing both though.

Comment: post your php code please

Comment: Don't post your PHP code.

Comment: Here is the php code

https://jsfiddle.net/n2cs7p9s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a GROUP BY clause. You probably want to group on `produkter.p_id`, and use the aggregate function `MIN()`.

```
query = "
SELECT p.p_id
     , p.vare_nr
     , p.produkt_navn
     , p.beskrivelse
     , p.forhandler_pris
     , p.kunde_pris
     , p.kategori
     , p.teknisk_info
     , p.hmi_link
     , p.datablad
     , p.public
     , MIN(b.b_id)
     , b.navn
  FROM produkter p
  JOIN billeder b
    ON p.p_id = b.p_id
 WHERE p.kategori = 'leje'
 GROUP BY p.p_id
";
```

Comment: With that its not returning anything?

Comment: This is a MySQL question

Comment: @KristianTarp Woops, posted before thinking. I'll fix it.